# RabbitMQ Heroku add-on MQTT and STOMP support

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq, stomp, mqtt

I've noticed that Heroku has support for RabbitMQ. Is the add-on version supporting MQTT plugin and STOMP plugin?
 I'll look forward for your answers.
 Thank you.
  Regards,
   Florin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CloudAMQP](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudamqp) has STOMP enabled out of the box, but for MQTT we recommend [CloudMQTT](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudmqtt) instead (which is currently in public beta on Heroku). RabbitMQ's MQTT adapter miss a couple of MQTT features, like QoS2 and retained messages.

Comment: Is webstomp only enabled in the $99/month plan? I need it for development and that's a bit more than I'd like to pay just to test the app (I don't mind once we go into production).